# work with PHP_SELF

Tags: php, post, self

It give me this error :  Undefined index: action in  LINE  :  `$act=$_POST['action'];`

```
<?php
 function_2()
    {

    ?> 
 <FORM name="poll" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert">
      .
      .
      .

</FORM> 



<?php 
        }
    $act=$_POST['action'];
    switch($act)
    {
        case "insert":

            function_1();
            break;
        default:
            fuction_2();
            break;
    }
?>
```

please help me about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is saying that `$_POST['action']` doesn't exist. So, you will need a conditional statement to set that value of $act.

```
// Set Default
$act = '';
if ( isset($_POST['action'])) ) {
    $act = $_POST['action'];
}

switch($act)
{
    case "insert":

        function_1();
        break;
    default:
        fuction_2();
        break;
}
```